# Why is $f(x)=\frac{-2}{x-3}$ a composite function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The way I recognize that $f(x)=\frac{-2}{x-3}\rightarrow f(u)=\frac{1}{u}$ with $u=g(x)=x-3$, is by acknowleding that $\frac{\delta}{\delta x}$ is a linear operator and therefore it cannot differentiate the whole function $f$ at once. My question is however, why is $f(x)$ a composite function? The only way I could explain it is by using circular logic, but it isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: Why do you say that the logic is circular?  The *definition* of composite is that $f(x)$ can be written as $f(x)=g(h(x))$; here $g(x)=\frac{-2}{x}$ and $h(x)=x-3$.

Comment: Take for example $z(x)=2x+6$ and the function $f$ from my question. Function $z(x)$ isn't a composite function whereas function $f(x)$ is a composite function. How do I recognize which function is composite and which isn't?

Comment: Every function is a composite function, albeit trivially (if $f:X\to Y$, then $f=\operatorname{Id}_Y\circ f$). There are more imaginative examples, not so trivial.

Comment: @MichaelBurr See my previous comment.

Comment: Every function is composite, for example, you could use your $z(x)=2x+6$ where $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=x+3$.  Then $z(x)=f(g(x))$.  I think that the question you're asking is very different from the one that you posted.  You are asking the question "How do I know by looking at a formula that I should  use the chain rule."  I suggest asking a new question with that question (if that is, indeed your question) because this post is off topic from that question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I created a separate topic for this see [this topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502523/how-do-i-know-by-looking-at-a-formula-that-i-should-use-the-chain-rule)

Answer (score 1):

EVERY function is a composite function. If $f(x)$ is some function then $f(x)=f(id(x))$ so $f(x)$ is some composite function.

In your case, we have $g(x)=\frac{-2}{x}$ and $h(x)=x-3$ and $f(x)=g(h(x))$.

Comment: What do you mean by f(id(x))f(id(x))?

Comment: @Matt $id(x)$ is the identity function