# How do I know by looking at a formula that I should use the chain rule?

Tags: calculus

As stated in the question "How do I know by looking at a formula that I should use the chain rule," take as an example the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-3}$.

Comment: Use the chain rule to do what? Differentiate? You can use whatever tool you want. In this case $f = g \circ h$ where $h(x) = x-3$ and $g(y) = {1 \over y}$.

Answer (score 1):

You use the chain rule when clearly f(x) = g(h(x)).  Here if h(x) = x - 3 and g(x) = 1/x then g(h(x)) = 1/(x - 3) = f(x).  So you could use the chain rule.

Although, I'm not sure to what degree I would say that is "clearly".  It screams out for the quotient rule sooner than the chain rule to me.

Comment: I always use the chain rule to differentiate $f(x)/g(x)$ because I already know the product rule and the chain rule by heart (you can't do any calculus without them) and I can't be bothered to remember the quotient rule.

Comment: The negative signs of the quotient rule always throw me off too.

Comment: @Rahul personally, I would now just use the multi-variate chain rule.  None of this required, all you have to do is break the problem into pieces you can differentiate.  But to the OP here, saying that likely isn't helpful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your function $f(x)$ shows that it is shown to be in the form of $g[h(x)]$ where you know how to differentiate $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ but don't know how to directly differentiate $f(x)$, then yes, you should use chain rule.  In your example, the quotient rule would work just as fine and in Calculus, many different methods can be used to approach any single problem.

An example that would require chain rule more obviously would be

$f(x)=e^{e^x}$

But even so, logarithmic differentiation would work, so it's all up to you to decide how to tackle it.